# How does an instruction decoder work?

Tags: assembly, arm, intel, cpu-architecture

In an assignment to instruction set, we are told to write a sequence of instructions for arithmetic operations needed in different architecture models: accumulator, stack, load/store, memory/memory.

Given:

- Opcode - 8 bits
- Memory addresses - 16 bits
- All registers are coded with 4 bits
- All data operands - 32 bits
- All instructions must be of an even number of bytes, i.e. 8 x N bits, where N is a natural number.

AND! **Addresses of registers can be packed together**

**Question 1:** When do we pack two registers together? How does the system know it's not one register coded into 4 bits? Could you please give me an example?

Say, we are given A = B + C. Instructions needed in the load/store model for this operation:

```
1. load r2, B;
2. load r3, C;
3. add r1, r2, r3;
4. store r1, A.
```

The 1st instruction is 28 bits long, so we need additional 4 bits.

**Question 2**: Does it make difference where to put the 4 bits in form of 0000? How would you make the instruction of a whole number of bytes?

I'll appreciate your help very much.

Comment: That'd be up to you on how you design your instruction set. Perhaps you need a `NOP` operator which is a do-nothing 4bit instructions you can stuff anywhere you end up with a non-32bit size.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please tell me, when do we want to pack two registers in one? F.e., I use registers r1 and r2 and encoded they look like 0001 and 0010. Can I write them both with only 4 bits? How would they look like? Something like 0110? I'm totally confused.

Comment: Like I said, that's up to you. it's your instruction set, and up to you to decide how to represent it.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question seems a bit vague, I'll risk an answer and maybe generate a useful discussion.

> **Question 1**: When do we pack two registers together? How does the system know it's not one register coded into 4 bits? Could you please
>   give me an example?

The **ID** (Instruction Decoder) in the CPU will read the opcode first. This means that once it knows the instruction it has to decode, *it knows how to interpret the following bits*. You can code your registers on 4 bits, meaning that you have 16 registers. But **imagine you have an instruction that is restricted to operate only on 2 registers from a subset of 4 registers**. In this case you can use only 4 bits to identify the 2 registers. In this way you packed in 4 bits the **"identificators"** of 2 registers.

> **Question 2**: Does it make difference where to put the 4 bits in form of 0000? How would you make the instruction of a whole number of
>   bytes?

**It counts where you put the 4 bits.** Depending on each opcode, the instruction decoder knows where to get the address of the register it uses. For example, for **load** instruction, if you designed the instruction to have the 4 bits just after the opcode, when the decoder identifies **load**, if will interpret the next 4 bits as register identifiers.

I don't believe you are constrained to use a whole number of bytes in the sense that **every bit in the instruction has a meaning**. The instruction can be a whole number of bytes by just containing some unused bits (usually at the end).